# How to create post using Google My Business API - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-my-business-api

I can't figure out why I'm getting the below error when I attempt to create a post with the GMB API in Google Apps Script. I'm following this documentation https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data

```
{

 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 2,
            "field": "summary",
            "message": "Standard local post must have at least a media or summary."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my script

```
function callToActionPost() {
  var url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123/locations/456/localPosts';


  var options = {
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + getGMBService_().getAccessToken() },
    method: 'POST',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    languageCode: "en",
    topicType: "STANDARD",
    summary: "New Release!",
    callToAction: {
      actionType: "ORDER",
      url: "https://www.artivem.com/"
    },
    media: {
      sourceUrl: "https://untappd.akamaized.net/photos/2021_04_16/ccff4c358e362ce3c4835fcc94549a8f_640x640.jpg",
      mediaFormat: "PHOTO"
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I tried the following adaption, but it did not work

```
function callToActionPost() {
      var url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123/locations/456/localPosts';
    
    
      var options = {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + getGMBService_().getAccessToken() },
        method: 'POST',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: {
        languageCode: "en",
        topicType: "STANDARD",
        summary: "New Release!",
        callToAction: {
          actionType: "ORDER",
          url: "https://www.artivem.com/"
        },
        media: {
          sourceUrl: "https://untappd.akamaized.net/photos/2021_04_16/ccff4c358e362ce3c4835fcc94549a8f_640x640.jpg",
          mediaFormat: "PHOTO"
        }
      }
      };
    
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log(response);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The request object needs to go into the payload.  "payload" is a parameter of the `options`.

```
function callToActionPost() {
  var url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123/locations/456/localPosts';

  var payload = {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "summary": "New Release!",
    "callToAction": {
      "actionType": "ORDER",
      "url": "https://www.artivem.com/"
    },
    "media": [{
      "sourceUrl": "https://untappd.akamaized.net/photos/2021_04_16/9999999999999999.jpg",
      "mediaFormat": "PHOTO"
    }]
  }
  
  var options = {
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + getGMBService_().getAccessToken() },
    method: 'POST',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
  
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    console.log("Error Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alan! That is what I tried as my adaption and it doesn't work. It does give me a different error though. Here's a snippet of the error for that method: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"summary\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'summary' could not be found in request message..." The error goes on to say that every parameter is unknown and invalid.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is converting the payload to a JSON string and making a setting for the content type.  See updated answer.

Comment: Here's a snippet of the error I receive when converting to a string: ""code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"languageCode\":\"en\",\"topicType\":\"STANDARD\",\"summary\":\"New Release!\",\"callToAction\":{\"actionType\":\"ORDER\",\"url\":\"https://www.artivem.com/\"}..." and here's a snippet of the error I receive keeping it as an object: ""error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"languageCode\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'languageCode' could not be found in request message..."

Comment: It looks like the `media` value is wrong.  It should be an array of objects according to the documentation.  And I'd put all the key names in double quotes and change the languageCode to en-US

Comment: @AlanWells How to get account id and location id?